# I cant remove ?author=N url to a nicename in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Probably should be something simple, but I looked at many sites a solution to my problem.

I'm trying to remove the url **?author=N** of a page of my site.
I want to change **www.mydomain.com/?author=13** to **www.mydomain.com/profile/username** So far I removed author url, however the id is still there.

My current code is:

```
}

    public static function get_profile_url($user_id = 0) {
        if ($user_id > 0) {
            $profile_url.="profile/" . $user_id;
        }
```

Not sure, but I think my target is **$user_id** I've used other alternatives such as **$user_nicename** but it still fails, any tips? thank you in advance for attention.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate friendly url in Options -> Permalinks. Do you have activated?

If yes, your url will be domain.com/author/user_name

Comment: My permalink its ok, the problem is in a post on the author's area, clicking it goes to this link as mentioned above (**?author=24**).

Comment: maybe you could use `get_author_posts_url` [function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url)?

Comment: I replaced the **get_profile_url** with **get_author_posts_url** and broke, do not worry, I did it on localhost :), did I put the code in the wrong place?

Comment: ... did you pass user id to get_author_posts_url... `get_author_posts_url( $user_id )`?... this should work :(((

Comment: did not work and broke again. you could put here as it should be the code? showing in full?

Comment: That is what i have in my single post file `<a class="url fn n" href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( "ID" ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author() ); ?>" rel="me"><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></a>`

Comment: The problem is not in the specific area of the author (single.php), but in a custom area that is below the "about the author" field, the code I mentioned above is in **user.php**. when I try to pass the mouse over the link, appears like this: **www.mysite.com/profile/34**.
My need is to replace the code to look like this: **www.mysite.com/profile/name**

Comment: If you want give me your theme code and i will see that... Maybe this theme has some filter in the functions.php for the user url...

Comment: www.ffgames.com.br/eventos/fln/2-fln-league-of-legends

take a look at this page and check down there where it says: "PARTICIPARAM DESTE EVENTO:"

There where the name, there would be users who participated in that event.